# Как правильно обрабатывать ошибки в fastapi?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, dao

Допустим, у меня есть роут, где я вызываю из DAO функцию создания пользователя. От нее, может прийти либо положительный ответ, либо оно может уже найти такого пользователя, либо может не обнаружить login/password. Как мне разделить эти ошибки и вывести соответствующую? То есть, что мне вернуть из DAO? Или же мне вызывать ошибку прямо в DAO? Желательно без try/except.